# Firebase Admin SDK Python TransportError max retries exceeded

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Trying to Fetch and modify data from the real-time database. No code change was done, working fine till yesterday.
Tried creating a new key, disabling service, updating packages. Nothing seems to work.

The code is used in Python Firebase Admin SDK. It is used to get and modify data from the real-time database.
I am using firebase_admin to access Firebase Realtime Database.

```
#Add Topics
topics=root.child('Topics/')
Category='Kabaddi'
with open('/Users/user/Desktop/balancerproject/single_sample.json') as response:
    data = json.load(response)
    #topics.update(data)
    topics.child(Category+'/').push(data)
    send_fcm(data)
    #instaQuotes(data.get('Title'))
```

It is throwing error in topics.child(Category+'/').push(data)

```
TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x10bb4b700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))
```

Comment: Please add the code you where running when u got  the error

Comment: You are not the only getting such errors. seems like there is some global bug. many others reported similar issues on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20gcloud&p=1)

Comment: For my case, I was using Airtel Fiber in India, when I switched to JIO it started working normally. Don't know if this would help.